# I'm unsure why none of my css transitions are working

Tags: html, css

So, I have a gallery that is laid out in a CSS grid. When I click on one of the items it opens info and images associated with that item. This info and images are also laid out in a grid.

My issue is that none of the transitions are working and I am not sure why and how to fix this.

```js
// portfolio
$('.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a').click(function() {
  var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.gallery .portfolio').addClass('item_open');
  $(itemID).addClass('item_open');
  return false;
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.port, .gallery .portfolio').removeClass('item_open');
  return false;
});

$(".gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.row img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #84b4b1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0 120px;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: .8;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1;
}

header p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 40px 0 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.gallery .portfolio {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  .gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -16px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3C%21--%20Generator%3A%20Adobe%20Illustrator%2017.1.0%2C%20SVG%20Export%20Plug-In%20.%20SVG%20Version%3A%206.00%20Build%200%29%20%20--%3E%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%0A%09%20id%3D%22svg2%22%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22http%3A//purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/%22%20xmlns%3Acc%3D%22http%3A//creativecommons.org/ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Ardf%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Asvg%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Asodipodi%3D%22http%3A//sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd%22%20xmlns%3Ainkscape%3D%22http%3A//www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape%22%20inkscape%3Aversion%3D%220.48.4%20r9939%22%20sodipodi%3Adocname%3D%22icon-fullscreen.svg%22%0A%09%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20960%20560%22%0A%09%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20960%20560%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Csodipodi%3Anamedview%20%20borderopacity%3D%221%22%20pagecolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20bordercolor%3D%22%23666666%22%20objecttolerance%3D%2210%22%20gridtolerance%3D%2210%22%20guidetolerance%3D%2210%22%20showgrid%3D%22false%22%20fit-margin-top%3D%220%22%20fit-margin-left%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Azoom%3D%227.375%22%20inkscape%3Acx%3D%22-5.1525424%22%20inkscape%3Acy%3D%2216%22%20id%3D%22namedview11%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-x%3D%22-8%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-y%3D%22-8%22%20fit-margin-right%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Apageopacity%3D%220%22%20fit-margin-bottom%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-width%3D%221366%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-height%3D%22706%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-maximized%3D%221%22%20inkscape%3Apageshadow%3D%222%22%20inkscape%3Acurrent-layer%3D%22svg2%22%3E%0A%09%3C/sodipodi%3Anamedview%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%22220%22%20y%3D%22260%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%20width%3D%22536%22%20height%3D%2224%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%22476%22%20y%3D%224%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%20width%3D%2224%22%20height%3D%22556%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A) no-repeat;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
  transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a:hover:before {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
}

.gallery .portfolio .portfolio-group a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery .portfolio-item-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .gallery .portfolio-item-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

.port {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 103;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  transition: (all, 0.5s, ease-in-out);
}

.port img {
  width: 100%;
}

.port h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.port h1>* {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: (all, 0.5s, linear);
}

.port.item_open {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: (all, 0.4s, ease-in-out);
}

.port.item_open>* {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3C%21--%20Generator%3A%20Adobe%20Illustrator%2017.1.0%2C%20SVG%20Export%20Plug-In%20.%20SVG%20Version%3A%206.00%20Build%200%29%20%20--%3E%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%0A%09%20id%3D%22svg2%22%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22http%3A//purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/%22%20xmlns%3Acc%3D%22http%3A//creativecommons.org/ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Ardf%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Asvg%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%0A%09%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2021%2021%22%0A%09%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2021%2021%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cg%20id%3D%22layer1%22%20transform%3D%22translate%280%2C-1031.3622%29%22%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20id%3D%22path2987%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C1031.4l21%2C21%22/%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20id%3D%22path2989%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20d%3D%22M21%2C1031.4l-21%2C21%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A%0A) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1004;
  transition: (all, 0.1s, ease-in-out);
}

.item_open .close {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  transition: (all, 0.3s, ease-in-out);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body translate="no" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="8.896.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <header>
    <h1>Portfolio Gallery</span>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <div id="top"></div>

  <!-- Projects -->
  <section class="gallery clearfix">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="portfolio">
        <a class="close" href="#"></a>
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #1 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3892302/contact.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #2 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4154721/dive--001.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #3 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3695553/news.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #4 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3695553/news.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #5 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4360101/liberosis_--_12.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #6 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3148799/technical-book.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #7 -->
        <div class="portfolio-group">
          <a href="#item02">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/2883479/cover.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- / div #8 -->
      </div>
      <!-- / .portfolio  -->
    </div>
    <!-- / .row -->

    <!-- Item 01-->
    <div id="item01" class="port">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="description">
          <h1>Item 01</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.
        </div>
        <!-- / .description -->
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- / .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- / #item01-->

    <!-- Item 02-->
    <div id="item02" class="port">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="portfolio-item-container">
          <div class="description">
            <h1>Item 02</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.
          </div>
          <!-- / .description -->
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="dist/image/CAHQ-About-Us.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4360101/liberosis_--_12.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4360101/liberosis_--_12.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / .portfolio-item-container -->
      </div>
      <!-- / .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- / #item02-->

  </section>
  <!-- / Projects -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, it shows my problem! The problem comes in when you click on an item and also when you click on the X to close the content that opened up. The transitions are not working. I have them in my CSS code but they don't work when I view the document.

Comment: Also, I validated my HTML and it says there are no problems. So, I don't know why it is showing up that way here.

Comment: Thank you! That was actually my mistake when I created this post. I have it right in my code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just figured out the problem! I appreciate you taking the time to look at my code.

Comment: The format of your transitions is incorrect. Remove the brackets and the commas. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Please post an answer below to resolve your post. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I made a mistake in having the transition code in parentheses. With that fix, everything works and !